# Skeleton tracking with 2D camera

Tags: c#, camera, computer-vision

I'm trying to use a 2D camera to recognize the device/object a user is pointing at so I was looking for a skeleton tracking software using a 2D camera in order to be able to do that. Is there any open source project that deals with skeleton tracking using 2D cameras?

(I've gone through tons of links on Google and it seems like most of what's there is just research papers but no actual open source projects)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's kind of a pre-release of a SDK for Kinect from Microsoft. Perhaps this might be helpful for you:

http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/11249/

(Although I think this won't be Open Source. But since you are using c#, a Microsoft SDK might be ok for you.)

Comment: C# is an ECMA standard and is open source. You're thinking of the .NET framework, which is closed source.

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking Microsoft's C# implementation. Sorry.

Comment: It uses the 3D camera (and not 2D camera) doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

[Skamleton](http://sourceforge.net/projects/skamleton/) could be an option. It's an open-source project in early stages, but it implements a background subtractor, a skin color classifier, blob tracking and face classification. There is a [demo on YouTube](http://youtu.be/snUgm8lNsaY).

Note Skamleton use simple cameras, not RGB-D (depth) cameras as the Kinectic system (Kinect uses a structured light device from PrimSense).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an old post, but in case anyone is still looking Extreme Reality uses a regular webcam and does skeleton tracking.  It's not open source, but I've played around with it a bit and it does seem to be fairly robust.

http://www.xtr3d.com/developers/resources/